# Automapper create map method

Tags: c#, automapper

Im working with automapper and was wondeeing about this thing, Is create map works two way,
Do i need to create map from entity to dto and from dto to entity,
One of them is good enought?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It only works one way, you will have to create both maps.